# What advantages does the iloc function have in pandas and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I just began to learn Python and Pandas and I saw in many tutorials the use of the iloc function. It is always stated that you can use this function to refer to columns and rows in a dataframe. However, you can also do this directly without the iloc function. So here is an example that yield the same output:

```
# features is just a dataframe with several rows and columns
features = pd.DataFrame(features_standardized)

y_train = features.iloc[start:end] [[1]]
y_train_noIloc = features [start:end] [[1]]
```

What is the difference between the two statements and what advantage do I have when using iloc? I'd appreicate every comment.

Comment: Try this on your DataFrame: `df.iloc[0, 0]` and `df[0, 0]`.  Or, if you prefer to use `loc` and a column  name, try this: `df.loc[0, 'colname']` and `df[0, 'colname']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), `iloc` provides:

> Purely integer-location based indexing for selection by position.

Therefore, as shown in the simplistic examples below, `[row, col]` indexing is not possible without using `loc` or `iloc`, as a `KeyError` will be thrown.

Example:

```
# Build a simple, sample DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4]})

# No iloc
>>> df[0, 0]
KeyError: (0, 0)

# With iloc:
>>> df.iloc[0, 0]
1
```

The same logic holds true when using `loc` and a column name.

#### What is the difference and when does the indexing work without iloc?

The short answer:
Use `loc` and/or `iloc` when indexing rows *and* columns.  If indexing on row *or* column, you can get away without it, and is referred to as **'slicing'**.

However, I see in your example `[start:end][[1]]` has been used.  It is generaly considered bad practice to have back-to-back square brackets in pandas, (e.g.: `[][]`), and generally an indication that a different (more efficient) approach should be taken - in this case, using `iloc`.

The longer answer:
Adapting your `[start:end]` slicing example (shown below), indexing works without `iloc` when indexing (slicing) on **row only**.  The following example does not use `iloc` and will return *rows* 0 through 3.

```
df[0:3]
```

Output:

```
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

Note the difference in `[0:3]` and `[0, 3]`. The former (slicing) uses a *colon* and will return **rows** or indexes 0 through 3. Whereas the latter uses a *comma*, and is a `[row, col]` indexer, which requires the use of `iloc`.

Aside:
The two methods can be combined as show here, and will return rows 0 through 3, for column index 0.  Whereas this **is not** possible without the use of `iloc`.

```
df.iloc[0:3, 0]
```

Comment: But 'loc' does not allow integer indexing.  df.loc[0, "a"] does not work

Comment: @tnknepp - `loc` allows integer indexing for the row, provided the index is an integer.  In the example above, `df.loc[0, 'a']` does work, it returns `1`.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying.  I rarely use integer indexing, so it didn't work on my dataframe.  But you are right.  That may be a useful caveat to include in your answer.

Comment: Thanks S3DEV for your answer but I do not understand the code. What do you do in the line "df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4]})". Further as you can see from my posted example, it also works without iloc. What is the difference and when does the indexing work without iloc?

Comment: @  tnknepp: Thanks for your comment. Why do you not use integer indexing? What is the alternative?

Comment: @PeterBe Your index can be anything.  I do analysis on atmospheric data where date and altitude are important, so I typically use datetime values, or a combination of datetime and and altitude (see MultiIndex or multi-level indexing).

Comment: @PeterBe - I've updated the answer to hopefully address your question here in comments.

Comment: Thanks S3DEV for your answer and effort. Unfortunately I still do not understand it and do not see the benefits of using iloc. You wrote: " It is generaly considered bad practice to have back-to-back square brackets in pandas"--> If you look in my example you also have to use this when using iloc. It does not make a difference. Further your wrote "indexing works without iloc when indexing (slicing) on row only." Again have a look in my example. Here I use the statement "y_train_noIloc = features [start:end] [[1]]" and I index both rows [start:end] and columns [[1]]

Comment: In all my examples so far with dataframes I have not used iloc at all and I have never had a problem with it.

Comment: @PeterBe - Ok.  Try this on your DataFrame: `features[0, 0]` - index a row number and column number. You'll get a `KeyError`. Then, try it with `iloc`.  Additionally, this (`features [start:end] [[1]]`) works, yes ... but is poor practice and `iloc` should be used as `features.iloc[start:end, 1]` as its more efficient as (in the background) there is only a single indexing routine, rather than two.

Comment: Thanks S3DEV for your comment. But I can use features[1][1] without any problems and it produces the same results. So the iloc function is just for efficiency reasons that I can write features.iloc[1,1]. That is not a real benefit for me.

Comment: @PeterBe What version of pandas are you using (same for you S3DEV)?  Run pandas.__version__ to see version  number.  I'm on 0.24.2 (still) and for me features[0, 0] does not work.

Comment: Thanks tnknepp for your comment. Basically for me features[0, 0] does also not work. You have to use features [0][0] or features.iloc[0,0]. I use pandas version 1.1.3

Comment: @S3DEV: Are there cases where I can't access a row and column directly in R using indexes (without iloc)? So basically I'd use dataframe[a] [b]? Is this always possible (so far I did not encouter any problems).

Comment: I was referring to Python (Pandas) in my last comment not R.

Comment: Hi S3DEV, thanks for your comments. Is this always possible to use dataframe[a] [b] in Python?

Comment: Hi S3DEV, would you mind commenting on my last comments. I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: @PeterBe - As mentioned previously, you can access using `df[c][r]`, however it's un-Pythonic and considered poor practice.  `loc` / `iloc` are the preferred methods due to portability and efficiency - which are *very* important from a developer's point of view. From a basic analyst's point of view, it's 50/50.

Comment: ... additionally, when slicing is used on its own, this `df[:10]` will return the first 10 rows. However this `df[:10][:2]` will return the first two rows and 10 columns.  It's inconsistent. However, this `df.iloc[:10]` and `df.iloc[:10, :2]` *is* consistent.  Always [rows, columns].  TBH: If that alone isn't a reason to use `iloc`, I don't known what is.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I accepted your answer and upvoted it