# when subsetting with and without .loc[ ] in python?

Tags: python

I was doing a Python exercises and I got the wrong answer (in red). I'm a bit confused about subsetting with and without loc[ ]. Please enlighten me. Thank you.
[image: Datacamp exercise]

Comment: Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64461080/6340496) will help to clarify?  (Not strictly a duplicate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `df.loc[:, ['alignment', 'character']]` itself is a dataframe. What you're doing wrong is passing it inside `df`.

I suggest you to look around at the related [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thank you